# How to overwrite "wc_display_item_meta" function in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am looking to have an action included in my functions.php file **that changes the echo array from true to false** in the below code:

```php
function wc_display_item_meta( $item, $args = array() ) {
    $strings = array();
    $html    = '';
    $args    = wp_parse_args(
        $args,
        array(
            'before'       => '<ul class="wc-item-meta"><li>',
            'after'        => '</li></ul>',
            'separator'    => '</li><li>',
            'echo'         => true,
            'autop'        => false,
            'label_before' => '<strong class="wc-item-meta-label">',
            'label_after'  => ':</strong> ',
        )
    );
```

The above code is found in the WooCommerce [wc-template-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8e45860732d9c4dd5cb1899c106c089717f19964/includes/wc-template-functions.php) file found on line 3273.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you really need to change the function itself? `wp_parse_args` merges the default arguments inside the function, with the arguments passed in via the `$args` parameter in the function _call_ - so if you need to set `echo` to false, you should be able to do it in _that_ place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [includes/wc-template-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8e45860732d9c4dd5cb1899c106c089717f19964/includes/wc-template-functions.php), you will see that the function in there is wrapped in a `if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_display_item_meta' ) ) {` conditional.

So redefine the same function in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme) and your custom function will override the existing.

**Note:** A function can only be reassigned this way once.

So you get:

```php
/**
 * Display item meta data.
 *
 * @since  3.0.0
 * @param  WC_Order_Item $item Order Item.
 * @param  array         $args Arguments.
 * @return string|void
 */
function wc_display_item_meta( $item, $args = array() ) {
    $strings = array();
    $html    = '';
    $args    = wp_parse_args(
        $args,
        array(
            'before'       => '<ul class="wc-item-meta"><li>',
            'after'        => '</li></ul>',
            'separator'    => '</li><li>',
            'echo'         => false,
            'autop'        => false,
            'label_before' => '<strong class="wc-item-meta-label">',
            'label_after'  => ':</strong> ',
        )
    );

    foreach ( $item->get_formatted_meta_data() as $meta_id => $meta ) {
        $value     = $args['autop'] ? wp_kses_post( $meta->display_value ) : wp_kses_post( make_clickable( trim( $meta->display_value ) ) );
        $strings[] = $args['label_before'] . wp_kses_post( $meta->display_key ) . $args['label_after'] . $value;
    }

    if ( $strings ) {
        $html = $args['before'] . implode( $args['separator'], $strings ) . $args['after'];
    }

    $html = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_display_item_meta', $html, $item, $args );

    if ( $args['echo'] ) {
        // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
        echo $html;
    } else {
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems sketchy, but it does work. It's a lot of redundant code to maintain as WC core changes over time.